# Filttering json data in html-table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have to display json data in HTML-table and have succeeded in it. My problem is that I also need to filter this data by genders and studyfields using radiobuttons and dropdown list in the webpage. I have managed to do so but the filters clash with each other and mess the results in the table.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h4>Filter by Gender</h4>
    <label>All</label>
    <input class="filter-by-gender" checked="checked" type="radio" id="filterByGenderAll" value="all" name="filter_by_gender">
    <label>Males</label>
    <input class="filter-by-gender"  type="radio" id="filterByGenderM" value="male" name="filter_by_gender">
    <label>Females</label>
    <input class="filter-by-gender" type="radio" id="filterByGenderF" value="female" name="filter_by_gender">
    <br><br>
    <h4>Filter by Studies</h4>
    <select id="filterByStudiesAll" input class="filter-by-studies" name="filter-by-studies">
        <option value="All" name="filter-by-studies">All</option>
        <option value="Computer Science"name="filter-by-studies">Computer science</option>
        <option value="Business"name="filter-by-studies">Business</option>
        <option value="Art"name="filter-by-studies">Art</option>            
    </select>

</div>
<table id="students">
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Studyfield</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Address</th>

    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody" id="personsTable">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Json is like this:

```
var students = [
{
"student_id": "123456",
"age": 20,
"firstname": "Horne",
"lastname": "Hess",
"gender": "male",
"study_field": "Computer Science",
"email": "hornehess@magnafone.com",
"phone": "+1 (877) 436-3132",
"address": "745 Livingston Street, Cassel, South Dakota, 103"}]
```

and lastly javascript:

```
       function filterStudentsByGender(gender)
            {
            var filteredStudents = students
            switch(gender)
            {
        case "male":

            filteredStudents = students.filter(function(student){
                return student.gender === "male"
            })
        break;

        case "female":
            filteredStudents = students.filter(function(student){
                return student.gender === "female"
            })
        break;
    }

    var studentsHtml = filteredStudents.map(function(student){
        return '<tr><td>'+student.firstname+" "+student.lastname+'</td><td>'+student.gender+'</td><td>'+student.age+'</td><td>'+student.study_field+"</td><td>"+student.email+"</td><td>"+student.phone+"</td><td>"+student.address+"</td></tr>";
    })      
    $("#students").find('.tbody').html(studentsHtml)

}
function filterStudentsByStudy(study_field)
{   
    var filteredStudents=students
    switch(study_field){
        case "Computer Science":
        filteredStudents=students.filter(function(student){
            return student.study_field=="Computer Science"
        })
        break;

        case "Art":
        filteredStudents=students.filter(function(student){
            return student.study_field=="Art"
        })
        break;

        case "Business":
        filteredStudents=students.filter(function(student){
            return student.study_field=="Business"
        })
        break;
    }
    var studentsHtml = filteredStudents.map(function(student){
        return '<tr><td>'+student.firstname+" "+student.lastname+'</td><td>'+student.gender+'</td><td>'+student.age+'</td><td>'+student.study_field+"</td><td>"+student.email+"</td><td>"+student.phone+"</td><td>"+student.address+"</td></tr>";
    })

    $("#students").find('.tbody').html(studentsHtml)
}

/* ########################## event listeners */
$(".filter-by-studies").on("change", function(e){
    var checked = $(this).val();
    filterStudentsByStudy(checked)
})

$(".filter-by-gender").on("change", function(e){
    var checkedValue = $(this).val();
    filterStudentsByGender(checkedValue)
})
```

Comment: you need to combine all your separate filtering operations into one which takes into account all of the selected values simultaneously and produces one final set of results, having filtered it by all of the fields.